# Is it possible to access a clobbered alias without Remove-Item?

Tags: powershell, language-lawyer

Suppose there is an alias defined in the PowerShell session like so:

```
Set-Alias Write-Host BadAliasName
```

Where `BadAliasName` is defined elsewhere and does nothing. `BadAliasName` could be anything, even another cmdlet in the PowerShell library.

The cmdlet named `Write-Host` is now clobbered. Is it possible to execute the original/underlying `Write-Host` without first doing `Remove-Item alias:Write-Host`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prefix with the module name like this:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the call (&) operator with the command's `commandinfo` object as in: `& (Get-Command -type cmdlet Write-Host) Hello`